# What do I need to program an ATmega 168?

Tags: atmega, programming, breadboard, programmer, isp

I use AVR Studio for my compilation and c/c++ code (***not*** arduino).So far I have used a **[Atmega 2560 development board](http://www.nex-robotics.com/products-topmenu-45.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=556&category_id=47)** provided by  Nex robotix.

I have **ISP programmers** of the following sorts...
**[AVRISP mkII USB Programmer](http://www.nex-robotics.com/products-topmenu-45.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=127&category_id=7)**
and **[NEX AVR USB ISP STK500V2](http://www.nex-robotics.com/products-topmenu-45.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=810&category_id=7)**.

Now I need to do some programming on low end microcontrollers like **ATmega 168** (28 pins).
I just have the raw chip. Can I program it on breadboard,or **must I buy a development board?**

After programming the chip can I use it on breadboard with Vcc, GND and the pins I need for my application?

Comment: http://www.nex-robotics.com/products-topmenu-45.html?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=894&category_id=6
I have used this dev brd for atmega 2560 before,If it helps.

Comment: As a side question, will the programmer mentioned as answers also do software debugging as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this no problem. I have a setup on my desk doing this right now. Follow this tutorial and it will explain it to you:

http://avrprojectsfiuady.blogspot.com/2011/07/programming-avr-with-avrisp-mkii.html

If you are running the new AVR Studio also watch this video to help get you setup:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTTZUpzAjKc

(You will need AVRDUDE installed as well).

Answer (score 1):

Your AVR ISPmkII will program your chip just fine. [Application Note AVR910](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0943.pdf) provides the details. The pinout of your ISP header is:

[image: ISP pinout]

Match those pins up to the pins of the AtMega168, and you should be programming the device straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can program ATMega168 on a breadboard. It works just fine because I have done that in the past using ISP programmer. It is best to use a regulator for Vcc. I believe this chip works on 3.3V so LM2937 regulator would be good. I used AVR Dragon debugger which worked like a breeze.

Comment: Thanks but what should be the pin connection ? I am a complete noob.What are the pins that are to be connected? Any suggestions or circuit diagram?